# How to simplify jQuery code to highlight areas and links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to relate highlighted areas and links: `square1`-`linkone`; `square2`-`linktwo`; `square3`-`linkthree`; ...

The following code works, but is cumbersome and error-prone; is there any way to simplify it for many areas and links?

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $('.map').maphilight();

  $('#linkone').mouseover(function() {
    $('#square1').mouseover();
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $('#square1').mouseout();
  });

  $("#square1").on({
    mouseover:function(){
      $("#linkone").css("color","red");},
    mouseout:function() {
      $('#linkone').css("color","green");
    }
  });

  $('#linktwo').mouseover(function() {
    $('#square2').mouseover();
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $('#square2').mouseout(); 
  });

  $("#square2").on({
    mouseover:function(){
      $("#linktwo").css("color","red");},
    mouseout:function() {
      $('#linktwo').css("color","green");
    }
  });

  $('#linkthree').mouseover(function() {
    $('#square3').mouseover();
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $('#square3').mouseout(); 
  });

  $("#square3").on({
    mouseover:function(){
      $("#linkthree").css("color","red");},
    mouseout:function() {
      $('#linkthree').css("color","green");
    }
  });

  $('#linkfour').mouseover(function() {
    $('#square4').mouseover();
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $('#square4').mouseout(); 
  });

  $("#square4").on({
    mouseover:function(){
      $("#linkfour").css("color","red");},
    mouseout:function() {
      $('#linkfour').css("color","green");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: give your markup also..

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to find all all elements that has an Id that contains a specified string

```
$("[id*='link']")
```

Or you could give all elements that you would like to perform the same action on a class, and then find the elements by class instead

```
$(".colorgreen").css("color,"green")
```

Read more about selectors in the documentation [api.jquery.com/category/selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)